# How to know which package provides a header file via “dnf” command

Tags: linux, dnf

I know `dnf provides` could find a package which includes a specific command, for example,

```
$ dnf whatprovides g++
Last metadata expiration check: 0:57:32 ago on Wed May 20 09:43:51 2020.
gcc-c++-9.3.1-2.wf31.x86_64 : C++ support for GCC
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Provide    : g++ = 9.3.1-2.wf31

gcc-c++-9.3.1-2.wf31.x86_64 : C++ support for GCC
Repo        : release
Matched from:
Provide    : g++ = 9.3.1-2.wf31
```

But when I need a header file, I want to find out its package name similar like `dnf provides a-header-file-name`, but it doesn't work. For example,
    $ dnf provides cm/api/transactionmanager.hpp
    Last metadata expiration check: 1:01:49 ago on Wed May 20 09:43:51 2020.
    Error: No Matches found

```
$ dnf provides transactionmanager.hpp
Last metadata expiration check: 1:01:55 ago on Wed May 20 09:43:51 2020.
Error: No Matches found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting a wild card at the front may help. For example:

This does **not** work:

`dnf provides types.h`

`Error: No Matches found`

But this does work:

`dnf provides */types.h`

Comment: Great, this works for me, thank you!